# Tableau Load Hive Metadata

Tags: hive, tableau-api

Is it possible to read/load Hive metadata in Tableau?

For example, I want to build a Tableau report that has all databases' names. In Hive, I can use `show databases` to get the full list of databases; but how can I load the result to Tableau?

Answer (score 2):

Hive's metadata is stored in an external RDBMS.
Currently supported RDBMS - MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server and also Derby.
All you need is to access the RDBMS and query it.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+MetastoreAdmin#AdminManualMetastoreAdmin-SupportedBackendDatabasesforMetastore